# Not able to set style properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying change the following code:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.mover');
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
  var phase = Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop / 1250) + (i % 5));
  items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase + 'px';
}
```

into this...

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.mover');
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phases[i % 5] +  
  'px';
  console.log(items[i].style.left);
}
```

Variable phases is an array that is global in scope and defined elsewhere in the js file. The `console.log()` output is showing me that the assignment is working properly, but the page isn't updating when I use the static phases array instead of the `Math.sin()` function. 
I've tried other solutions, but if I'm not passing result of `Math.sin()`, it doesn't work. I'm doing this to avoid having to call `Math.sin` on every iteration.

Here is the `CSS`, which hasn't changed:

```
.mover {
  position: fixed;
  width: 256px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you arent using jQuery?

Comment: can  you post your phases array as well, so we can see what that looks like?

Comment: Make sure that the expression you are copying to the `items[i].style.left` isn't NaN as that would be a NOP.

Comment: What is `items[i].basicLeft`? That doesn't seem to be a standard DOM property.

Comment: Never heard about `basicLeft`, any reference anyone?

Comment: Here's the array: phases = [0.10938070962633038, 0.8955207494222001, 0.8583231421048282, 0.0319871962962512, -0.8237576302705858]; I got the values from console.log ing the original Math.sin() function. I know that the expression I'm copying to items[i].style.left works, because I'm getting updated values of items[i].style.left like the following: 1802.94px, 89.5521px, 341.832px.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88513/putting-items-in-a-sinusoidal-arrangement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Is a way!

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.mover');
var phase = []
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  phase.push(Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop / 1250) + (i % 5)));
}

for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phases[i % 5] +  
  'px';
  console.log(items[i].style.left);
}
```

Comment: removed the runnable, my intention was to show how the phase array should be populated.... Thanks